# Docker CMD not working depending on the device I use to build the image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker image that ends with a CMD instruction (CMD /entrypoint.sh). This image has been working for several years, actually is working right now (I was developing with Mac and also with Windows 11 and works fine with both of them, as expected):

```bash
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
WORKDIR /home/mydir
CMD /entrypoint.sh
```

The problem is that with other computer with Windows (Windows 10 in this case) is not working. When the docker image is started (with docker-compose) the following error message shouws up in the image container logs:

```bash
/entrypoint.sh not found
```

The docker image is exactly the same, I think is not a problem related to the docker version but here are the versions we are using:

```bash
Docker version 20.10.17 on Windows 11: Working
Docker version 20.10.12 on Windows 10: Failing
Docker version 20.10.12 on Mac OSX: Working
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you running the container?  (Are there any bind mounts from the hosts overwriting these files?)  Do you get a different error if you use JSON-array exec syntax `CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]` (without running an intermediate shell)?

Comment: I am running the container with docker-compose (docker-compose up -d) and trying CMD [] also leads to the same error (also with ENTRYPOINT entrypoint.sh) it's like the file is not being copied to the image ...